# Fragment layout ambiguity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a project with 99 fragments. A client wants us to make our BottomNavigationView semi-transparent and have our content scroll behind it. But not all our fragments are scrollable. Some are RelativeLayouts with controls attached to the bottom of the page that need to not allow themselves to go down past the BottomNavigationView, so that they're not covered up. And even with the pages that scroll, sometimes it's not even the entire page that scrolls, but just a subset of it. Is there any way I can achieve this kind of ambiguity without going through all 99 of my fragments and making a unique judgement call on each or them?

Comment: Achieving a single solution for 99 differently behaving fragments seems not possible. You have to update the layouts based on the purpose by adding padding and bottom spacing as necessary. But one thing I still do not understand is how do you have 99 fragments when Android recommends only 5 for bottom navigation?

Comment: We only have 4 or 5 that are actually controlled by the BottomNavigationView. The rest you get to via other controls within the fragments themselves.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct solution as such for what you are trying to achieve.

If your fragments has `RecyclerView` then add extra `bottomSpacing` for last item in the list in `ItemDecoration` class.

If your fragment has `ScrollView` then add extra `paddingBottom` for last view in the hierarchy.

If your view has anything other than these two scrolling views, then you can hardcode the bottom margin and give a color below matching to the navigation view. This make it look opaque from translucent.

One thing that is understood is the bottom spacing, margin and padding will be equal to or slightly greater than (ideally height + 8dp) you bottom navigation.

Since you fragments behave differently, there is no use of trying to make single solution for the same. **But to make the job easier for future, you can externalise these margins and spacings in dimens.xml (use same object for all the spacing) and hence in future if any requirement changes, you can change the spacing directly from the dimens.**

And you can do the same for bottom navigation spacing color, externalize to colors.xml and change it as you like.